# To map data generated from backend to checkboxes in angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm facing one problem!

Here all underwriter records are fetched from mysql database and shown now  I want to add some records to list by using checkboxes but I dont know how to bind autogenerated data to checkboxes using "userid"and also to add it in list.

Can anyone help me?

Here I used Angular 4 for frontend development and mysql database for backend.

Here I,m sharing my angular 4 code snippet ....
////underwriter.component.html

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Application Id</td>
            <td>Plan Id</td>
            <td>User Id</td>
            <td>Plan Name</td>
            <td>Plan Type</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Salary</td>
            <td>Dependents</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Sum Assured</td>
            <td>Approval records</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let ud of underwriterdata" [value]="ud.user_id">
            <td>{{ud.app_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.plan_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.plan_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.plan_type}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.category}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.salary}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.dependents}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.status}}</td>
            <td>{{ud.sum_assured}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button (click)="approveRecords()" class="button">Approve</button>
```

Comment: you want to add new editable row(s) to the table?

Comment: No, I want to add records from table to the list using checkboxes.